# Python Pandas dataframe: how to group values from different columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need help with cleaning my dataframe.
The dataframe is the following:

```
         Gap      Date          Time      Full text   Retweets   Likes
0   3.160003  2018-05-21    03:30:56  @georgechang..  19         462
1   3.160003  2018-05-21    21:15:03  @reveal         141        1610
2   3.160003  2018-05-21    11:25:21  RT @nova_road:  2030       0
3   3.160003  2018-05-21    07:10:01  @MrsYomaddy     48         917
4   3.160003  2018-05-21    07:06:54  @Dani21 @dmatki 40         5367
```

As you can observe, for all the rows the Gap value is equal to the Date value.

What I would like to obtain is the following dataframe:

```
                         num    Time      Full text    Retweets   Likes
    Gap       Date         
0   3.160003  2018-05-21    1     03:30:56  .....        19      462
1                           2     21:15:03  .....        141     1610
2                           3     11:25:21  .....        2030    0 
3                           4     07:10:01  .....        48      917
4                           5     07:06:54  .....        40      5367
```

where num is an extra column with the number of tweets.

I already asked a similar question but now the problem is a bit different.
Here is the link. [How can I create a multiindex data frame with the following datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758521/how-can-i-create-)
a-multiindex-data-frame-with-the-following-datasets

What i tried to do is the following code:

```
StockbyTweets.set_index(['Date','Gap','Time'],inplace=True)
StockbyTweets
```

but what I got is only this:

```
                           Time       Full text    Retweets   Likes
    Gap       Date         
0   3.160003  2018-05-21    03:30:56  .....        19        462
1                           21:15:03  .....        141       1610
2                           11:25:21  .....        2030      0 
3                           07:10:01  .....        48        917
4                           07:06:54  .....        40        5367
```

How do i get an additional column with the number of tweet?

Comment: What I tried to do is the following:

Answer (score 0):

`set_index` is what you are looking for:[Documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df.set_index(['Gap','Date'])
```

Didn't notice the other part of the question.

Here is the number of tweets column:

```
level_name = df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()
level_name = [str(i).split(' ')[0] for i in level_name]
level_name = list(set(level_name))

num_of_tweets = {}
for i in level_name:
    df1 = df.loc[i]
    num_of_tweets[i] = len(df1)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['num_of_tweets'] = 0
for key in num_of_tweets.keys():
    
    df.loc[df['Gap'] == key,'num_of_tweets'] = num_of_tweets[key]

# set the index again.
```

The logic is a bit round about, and probably isn't the best way to go about this.

However the logic can be used to get any combination of columns.

Comment: Python gives me  an 'Invalid type comparison' error in StockbyTweets.loc[StockbyTweets['Gap'] == key,'num_of_tweets'] = num_of_tweets[key]

Comment: Does it tell which types?